# Cannot find file libil2cpp.dbg.so to copy - :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask

Tags: android, azure, unity-game-engine, gradle, il2cpp

I'm building a Unity project for Android on a Windows VM and, when I run Azure DevOps pipelines, I get the following error message:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask'.
> Warning: Could not find file [Path here]\jniLibs\arm64-v8a\libil2cpp.dbg.so to copy.
```

It happens when I run a task:

```
  - bash: |
      chmod +x '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)\...path...\il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\netcoreapp3.1'
      chmod +x gradlew
      ./gradlew assembleRelease --stacktrace --info
      ./gradlew generateAPIDoc
```

At first, it seemed to me that /libil2cpp.dbg.so won't be found as it is moved to /libil2cpp.so. On the VM, in unityLibrary/build.gradle, the following piece of code is present (it is not a part of code on repo):

```
def BuildIl2Cpp(String workingDir, String configuration, String architecture, String abi, String[] staticLibraries) {
    def commandLineArgs = []
    commandLineArgs.add("--compile-cpp")
    commandLineArgs.add("--platform=Android")
    commandLineArgs.add("--architecture=" + architecture)
    commandLineArgs.add("--outputpath=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
    commandLineArgs.add("--libil2cpp-static")
    commandLineArgs.add("--baselib-directory=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi)
    commandLineArgs.add("--configuration=" + configuration)
    commandLineArgs.add("--dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-report")
    commandLineArgs.add("--profiler-output-file=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_conv.traceevents")
    commandLineArgs.add("--print-command-line")
    commandLineArgs.add("--generatedcppdir=" + workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput")
    commandLineArgs.add("--cachedirectory=" + workingDir + "/build/il2cpp_"+ abi + "_" + configuration + "/il2cpp_cache")
    commandLineArgs.add("--tool-chain-path=" + android.ndkDirectory)
    staticLibraries.eachWithIndex {fileName, i->
        commandLineArgs.add("--additional-libraries=" + workingDir + "/src/main/jniStaticLibs/" + abi + "/" + fileName)
    }
    def executableExtension = ""
    if (org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem.current().isWindows())
        executableExtension = ".exe"
    exec {
        executable workingDir + "/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp" + executableExtension
        args commandLineArgs
        environment "ANDROID_SDK_ROOT", getSdkDir()
    }
    delete workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.sym.so"
    ant.move(file: workingDir + "/src/main/jniLibs/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.dbg.so", tofile: workingDir + "/symbols/" + abi + "/libil2cpp.so")
}
```

However, I also see that the pipeline cannot find a directory `/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp` and it's true - the directory does not exist in unityLibrary.

I wonder what I can do to create the directory that is not found, or at least stop the task from looking for the file, or look for /libil2cpp.so. <- I want to achieve at least one of the milestones of the issue.

I build the project with the following versions:

- Android Studio Arctic Fox: 2020.3.1
- Unity version: 2021.3.14f1
- Gradle version: 7.4

Pre-error messages printed in Azure DevOps:

```
> Transform artifact localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) with AarTransform
Transforming artifact localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) with AarTransform
Caching disabled for AarTransform: C:\Users\___\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\...\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0 because:
  Build cache is disabled
Skipping AarTransform: C:\Users\___\.gradle\caches\...\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0 as it is up-to-date.
AarTransform (Thread[Execution worker for ':' Thread 2,5,main]) completed. Took 0.007 secs.

> Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask
Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask in launcher Starting
Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask in unityLibrary Starting
Caching disabled for task ':unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask' because:
  Build cache is disabled
Task ':unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask' is not up-to-date because:
  Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
android.ndkVersion from module build.gradle is not set
ndk.dir in local.properties is C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.14f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/NDK
ANDROID_NDK_HOME environment variable is not set
sdkFolder is C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK
NDK side-by-side folder from sdkFolder C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\ndk does not exist
Considering C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK by ndk.dir
Considering C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder
Rejected C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\SDK\ndk-bundle in SDK ndk-bundle folder because that location has no source.properties
Found requested ndk.dir (C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK) which has version 21.3.6528147
Starting process 'command 'C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp.exe''. Working directory: C:\agent\_work\7\a\unityLibrary Command: C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp.exe --compile-cpp --platform=Android --architecture=arm64 --outputpath=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libil2cpp.so --libil2cpp-static --baselib-directory=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a --configuration=Release --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_conv.traceevents --print-command-line --generatedcppdir=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --cachedirectory=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache --tool-chain-path=C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
Successfully started process 'command 'C:/agent/..../unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/IL2CPP/build/deploy/il2cpp.exe''
C:\agent\...\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\il2cpp.exe --compile-cpp --platform=Android --architecture=arm64 --outputpath=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/jniLibs/arm64-v8a/libil2cpp.so --libil2cpp-static --baselib-directory=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/jniStaticLibs/arm64-v8a --configuration=Release --dotnetprofile=unityaot-linux --profiler-report --profiler-output-file=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_conv.traceevents --print-command-line --generatedcppdir=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/src/main/Il2CppOutputProject/Source/il2cppOutput --cachedirectory=C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache --tool-chain-path=C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK
Starting: C:\agent\...\unityLibrary\src\main\Il2CppOutputProject\IL2CPP\build\deploy\bee_backend\win-x64\bee_backend.exe --profile="C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/backend_profiler0.traceevents" --stdin-canary --dagfile="C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate/bee.dag" --continue-on-failure FinalProgram
WorkingDir: C:/agent/.../unityLibrary/build/il2cpp_arm64-v8a_Release/il2cpp_cache/buildstate
ExitCode: 0 Duration: 33s
Build succeeded with 0 successful nodes and 0 failed ones

Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask in launcher Finished
Task :unityLibrary:BuildIl2CppTask in unityLibrary Finished
```

Comment: Same issue here. Did you solve?

Comment: Hi, I've bypassed it but did not manage to solve the issue so it would be no help. I kept the question as I hope someone is able to provide the answer for those who still look for a solution.

Comment: Finally I got rid of the error by making a "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project" and the file libil2cpp.dbg.so gets generated again. I suppose some cache issues.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of the error by making a "Clean Project" and "Rebuild Project" and the file libil2cpp.dbg.so gets generated again. I suppose there were some cache issues